# What is this file? =#.##

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

I'm adding `react-dates` ( https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates ) to my NextJS project and I noticed this file.

File Name: `=#.##`

Contents:

```
+ moment@2.29.1
+ react-dates@21.8.0
+ react-dom@16.14.0
+ react@16.14.0
updated 4 packages and audited 389 packages in 2.205s

52 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

What is this for & can I just delete it?
It just looks like a terminal message.
¯_(ツ)_/¯

Thanks very much, in advance.

Comment: Looks like an install log.

Comment: Probably someone used `npm install <packages>` and wrongly used `>`, this redirected it to an output.

Comment: @aexander-santos (from their documentation) this was prob what did it: `npm install --save react-dates moment@>=#.## react@>=#.## react-dom@>=#.##`   ...ok, sounds like I can delete it. That's what I figured but wanted to be on the safe side. Thanks!